# Images are 'flicking' when downloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that get data from an instagram and there is a user feed, that updating each time user scroll to bottom. However, i notice, that when new portion of images show up, it 'flick' for a fraction of second (showing old photos). Thats not good.

Obviously there is a lot of code (i don't use libraries like AFNetworking and using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`), i will paste most important part:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.urlToPass];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location];
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//... there is the code
        }   else {

            NSArray *newPhotosFromFeed = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
            [self.photos addObjectsFromArray:newPhotosFromFeed];
        }


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });

    }];
    [task resume];
```

What i do, is checking if we have an array (old photos), and if we have, we add new photos to existing.

That is implementation of collectionViewCell:

myCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

```
if(!cell){

    cell = (myCell *)[myCell cell];
}

cell.photoDictionary = self.photos[indexPath.row];

NSLog(@" Count is %d", [self.photos count]);
return cell;
```

How to remove that nasty bug?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is obviously not with this code. My guess is that it is in your CollectionView implementation.

Comment: @StefanArentz please take a look at updated post.

Comment: Instead of reloading the whole collection view you should set image directly to cell or reload single cell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you posted for setting up the `UICollectionViewCell` comes from your `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` implementation ...

Instead if just setting `photoDictionary` there, you should also configure the cell's views. So that would actually be the place where you configure the image that the cell should show.

If the `photoDictionary` only contains a URL to the actual image, and the is downloaded separately, then what probably happens is that your cell still has old data in it. So it would still show an older image. In that case you want to set your cell's image view to display some placeholder image or maybe just a solid color.

You can also do the above, the resetting the cell, in your cell's `prepareForReuse` implementation.

Comment: Last time i had similar problem i fix it with following method (Using AFNetworking) - - (void)prepareForReuse {
    [self.myCellImageView cancelImageRequestOperation];
    self.myCellImageView.image = nil;
}. Maybe i should try to add that method.